# Javascript Calendar.Setup date format issue

Tags: javascript, c#, date, calendar

I have a C# page that has a javascript calendar on it and that caledar drives what information gets pulled for the user. The calendar is set up as follows:

```
if (document.getElementById("calendar-inputField")) {
            var cal_inp_fld_currvalue = "";
            var cal3 = Calendar.setup({
                inputField: "calendar-inputField",
                trigger: "calendar-inputField",
                dateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
                showsTime: false,
                animation: false,
                min: midDate,
                max: new Date(),
                fdow: 0,
                singleClick: true,
                step: 1,
                electric: false,
                onFocus: function () { cal_inp_fld_currvalue = document.getElementById('calendar-inputField').value; },
                onSelect: function () { this.hide(); if (cal_inp_fld_currvalue != document.getElementById('calendar-inputField').value) { ajax_call('qbonline.aspx?fn=AJAX', document.getElementById('idSelGetBatchType').value); } }
            });
```

the issue I'm having is with the dateformat, I found that if I use chrome and set my language settings to English (Canada) and I select a date like 05/23/2017 the calendar thinks that is an invalid date because the canadian date is viewed as dd/mm/yy.

What I want to know is if there is a way to ignore the users chrome settings and always use one format?

Comment: What is this `Calendar` object? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Perhaps `dateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y"` should be `dateFormat: "%d/%m/%Y"`? Just guessing, you haven't said which calendar you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I would like it to have the English US default of mm/dd/yyyy. And the calendar is a DHTML calendar widget created by dynarch I believe.